# Filtrar Dados de uma lista do Banco de dados com PHP apartir de um Input

Tags: php, array, button

Tenho um input text com o evento **onkeyup** no qual digito uma palavra e ele está comparando com uma lista do banco de dados e retornando um botão com o mesmo caso exista..

Eu quero que no decorrer que eu vá digitando vá surgindo as opções, exemplo:

Tenho uma lista com as palavras **teste,tornado,tempestade** e quando já digitar o t surgir as três opções e conforme for digitando vai excluindo algumas.

**Observações :**

Estou usando ajax para gerar os botões dinamicamente, mas procuro uma solução dentro do php para o problema

Por enquanto ele só ta comparando se a palavra for exatamente igual ao que digitei no input para imprimir o botão, eu quero que ele imprima os botões no decorrer que eu vá digitando.

Tem que ser com botão, não pode select nem opções como **datalist** do html5.

Comment: Tem como mostrar como estão sendo gerados os botões dinamicamente? Estou produzindo um script sem banco de dados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A única forma de fazer isso sem atualizar a página é com Ajax.

Para fazer isso você tem que usar o operador LIKE do sql junto com o %:

```
"SELECT coluna FROM tabela WHERE coluna LIKE '$variavel%' "
```

Onde '$variavel' é o retorno do teu input e o '%' diz que tem mais caracteres depois.

Nesse link tem mais coisas https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: Obrigado, tinha esquecido do like, solucionou perfeitamente o que eu procurava, apenas para complementar pra quem precisar, a sintaxe ficaria WHERE nome LIKE '%$AquiSeriaOvalor%' "; o valor entre % %, Abraço !

Comment: Se não for realmente necessário é melhor deixar o '%' só no final para poupar processamento do banco de dados.